# LibGDX tutorial help Scene2D

Tags: android, sprites, libgdx

I'm having trouble understanding this [tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2d).  It defines the importance of classes, but it doesn't show an outline of the project file so far.  From what I got from that tutorial was that there is a stage and actors.  Stage would be the static parts of the game, while the actors are the ones moving.  After that I got confused with the drawing method. I tried modifying it so I can draw a shape, but it wouldn't work.

How, if possible, would I create sprites using LibGDX's scene2d?

Answer (score 3):

You can find complete demo code on github and quick description on http://minimaldevelop.com/blog/libgdx-scene2d-game-example-code/

Answer (score 1):

Most people here will suggest that you post your code. Honestly, you don't have to use the Stage/Actor framework to create a game if you choose not to. There's a class called DecalBatch and even SpriteBatch that may help you to understand the process to render sprites. It might help to start there but again, it's hard to explain why it's not working without seeing what you have already tried.

Here's a link to the DecalBatch test code:
[http://libgdx.googlecode.com/DecalTest.java](http://libgdx.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/DecalTest.java)

If you post your code, I can revise my comments to include some suggestions to get something up and rendering.